# How to receive SOAP Message and convert it to JSON in spring boot java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, soap

Here I'm developing a service which is going to receive a SOAP request Message and then convert it into JSON. After that, I want to invoke a REST API with the converted JSON and then I want to receive the JSON response back from that REST API and finally I want to convert that JSON response into SOAP Response message and then send it back the caller service. So basically this service is going to act as a intermediate Wrapper service between SOAP and REST communication.

I've the WSDL with me and need a way to do this by using Spring boot. Could any help me here please?

Currently I'm doing as below -

```
@RestController
public class WrapperController {

  @PostMapping(
      value = "/wrap",
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Q248Req wrapSOAPRequest(@RequestBody String SOAPReq)
      throws SOAPException, IOException, JAXBException {
    System.out.println("SOAP Request: " + SOAPReq);
    SOAPMessage message =
        MessageFactory.newInstance()
            .createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(SOAPReq.getBytes()));
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestObj.class).createUnmarshaller();
    TestObj Req =
        (TestObj) unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

    return Req;
  }
```

I have generated the TestObj class from the supplied WSDL then I'm trying to map SOAP Message to TestObj class but it's throwing error -

```
SOAP Body: [#document: null]
2022-11-14 12:36:43.888 ERROR 21596 --- [nio-9080-exec-3] c.s.x.m.s.s.impl                         : SAAJ0251: Unable to extract Document from body
2022-11-14 12:36:43.896 ERROR 21596 --- [nio-9080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/wrapper-service/v1/decisions/q248] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to extract Document from body] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to class org.w3c.dom.Element (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.TextImpl and org.w3c.dom.Element are in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.BodyImpl.extractContentAsDocument(BodyImpl.java:338) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
    at com.lbg.rsk.cdp.core.controller.WrapperController.wrapSOAPRequest(WrapperController.java:265) ~[main/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

Comment: WSDL, generate object, receive object, call rest service, convert result to objkect, return object. As long as the object you receive for SOAP and REST is the same you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Yeah with the WSDL I can generate the Objects. But how do I map the incoming SOAP Request XML to my generated Java Object?

Comment: Request is not in Java object but in SOAP xml format and I need to map it to Java object. How do I do that?

Comment: You don't as that is what SPring Web Services does for you, so you don't need to map anything.

Comment: Can u refer me one example pls ? I mean I'm not able to work it out, how do I hold the SOAP XML as Java object in controller

Comment: You don't as you have an endpoint, not a controller. From the endpoint you use a resttemplate or webclient to send the object to the endpoint that needs JSON. As stated I strongly suggest to look at Spring Web Services (the SOAP project from the Spring portfolio).

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting you but I want it be a Stand-alone intermediate service which will do the conversion stuffs between SOAP & REST. I don't want to touch the existing SOAP/REST services. I want this service to be used as plugin which can be plugged in or of on the basis of need.

Comment: If you already have a SOAP service then what is the problem? I don't see hte issue then? You just write a new SOAP endpoint which receives the request, sends it out again to your endpoint. You are both overthinking this and making it overly complex.

Comment: See that SOAP service is a third party service and the REST too, I can't edit them so I opted for creating an intermediate service

Comment: Where did I say you need to edit those? You assumed something I didn't say.

Answer (score 0):

Just write and endpoint what does what you want.

```java
@Endpoint
public class YourEndpoint {

  public final RestTemplate rest;

  public YourEndpoint(RestTemplate rest) {
    this.rest=rest;
  }


  @PayloadRoot(localName="YourRequestFromWsdlRequest")
  @ResponsePayload
  public YourResponseFromWsdl method(@RequestPayload YourRequestFromWsdl) {
    return rest.postForObject(rest-url, YourRequestFromWsdl, YourResponseFromWsdl.class);
}
}
```

Instead of `RestTemplate` you could use an `WebClient`. But basically that is all you need. For the SOAP part Spring Web Services will do the conversion, for the JSON part Spring MVC will do the conversion. You don't need to to it yourself.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this so pardon for my trivial questions. I have the generated POJOs with me from the WSDL but what is this YourRequestFromWsdl that u r taking as @RequestPayload? I'm getting  - <soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Header>
...
</soap:Header>

<soap:Body>
...
  <soap:Fault>
  ...
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>, as a request body to this service then how do u form the actual object or pass this to the rest service?

Comment: That `YourRequestFromWsdl` is the object you already generated. The SOAP is just cruft. I really suggest you read up on what SOAP is and what Spring Web Services does. You are focussing on the wrong things.

Comment: What would be the url for this service? like how we define url path in @RequestMapping("/wrap"), how we do it here?

Comment: Again please read the Spring Web Services documentation. According to your question you are using Spring Boot include `spring-boot-starter-web-services` which will include everything you need. By default it will be available under `/services/whatever`. The URL doesn't matter, the content does it will route based on the content of the SOAP request.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I did exactly how u mentioned, I'm getting below error - Servlet.service() for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/wrapper-service/v1/decisions/q248] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/xml. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?;        Any clue?

Comment: Did you properly setup Spring Web Services? You need to tell it which classes to use/bind else it doesn't know what to do (you need to setup the `Jaxb2Marshaller`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try using  (com.ibm.json.xml.XMLToJSONTransformer) Library which help you to convert Soap String(i.e Request Body) to Json Object



String jsonObjectStr ="";

// convert String to JSONObject
jsonObjectStr = xmlToJsonTransformer.transform(SOAPReq);
  JSONObject.parse(jsonObjectStr);
```

Comment: It's not working